# VSCODE font change makes the font all italic?? (Cartograph CF)

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

So I installed & applied Cartograph CF font in settings (Font Family),
and also added this line in settings.json

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "Cartograph CF, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
```

The font has been applied, however, the problem is they are all italic. Even though I didn't add stuff like `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`. This seems only the case with Cartograph CF. Other fonts work just fine.

What could be the root cause of this, does anyone have any idea?
(p.s. I have installed all ttf files, not just italic ones.)

[This is what I see in my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udug1.png)

[And this is what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCLk.png)